# How to debug vars inside function at functions.php file?

Tags: functions, debug, wp-debug

I have this function:

```
function wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position( &$posts, $return = false ) {
    $ad_posts = array();

    $content_posts = array_filter(
        $posts,
        function ( $post ) {
            $position = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rw_adversiting_position', true );

            if ( empty( $position ) ) {
                return true;
            }

            $ad_posts[ intval( $position ) ] = $post;

            return false;
        } );

    $content_posts = array_values( $content_posts );

    ksort( $ad_posts );

    echo "sdfksfkjshdfsdf";

    foreach ( $ad_posts as $position => $ad ) {
        array_splice( $content_posts, $position, 0, $ad );
    }

    if ( $return ) {
        return $content_posts;
    } else {
        $posts = $content_posts;
    }
}
```

I need to debug `$ad_posts` after the `ksort()` but output is not going to browser. I did test with the `echo` you see there and that text also is not going to browser as output. How do I debug the values properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use `var_dump()` to do this. That is how I check values inside functions and filters.

I have the following line of code in a file which I simply copy and paste where needed to dump the value of a variable

```
?><pre><?php var_dump( $variable_to_test ); ?></pre><?php
```

The `pre` tags dump a nice readable array/object/string depending on the value. Inside your function you can just do

```
?><pre><?php var_dump($ad_posts); ?></pre><?php
```

after `ksort( $ad_posts );`.

Just make sure to call the function somewhere if it is not hooked to some kind of hook otherwise nothing will happen

Comment: Ohhh allright I was having some cache issues, forgot to disable the plugin and/or clear cache, anyway thanks

Comment: The best answer out there. I don't understand why people offer such complicated solutions when the answer is so simple. Maybe, it is because WP has become so complicated.

Answer (score 2):

To debug these values you don't have to display them in browser. Rather then do:

```
error_log(your-variable-or-whatever);
```

And check your error log in `wp-content/debug.log`.

To make it working you have to have `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` set in your `wp-config.php`.

EDIT:
As @nmr pointed out, `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` is also required.

Comment: `WP_DEBUG` must be enabled for `WP_DEBUG_LOG` to work.

Comment: `wp-content/debug.log` is not found. Is this a standard wordpress file?

Answer (score 2):

The proper and correct way to do this would be using XDebug and some kind of IDE that supports it, while working on development locally.

The easiest setup I can recommend would be using Local by Flywheel (free) for local development:
https://localbyflywheel.com/

Local has option under Utilities (for a site) to add XDebug configuration to PHPStorm, after clicking that button reopen the project in PHPStorm and you will see a debug configuration already setup for that site.

PHPStorm EAP (eap was free previously) can be downloaded here (also has 30 day trial):
https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2019/04/phpstorm-2019-1-2-preview-191-7141-5/

Docs on setting up XDebug:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

You can then set a breakpoint in your code and inspect it using XDebug.

The options above do work in a crunch, but the correct way to debug PHP is using an IDE and XDebug, and will save you TONS of time if you learn to do it the right way.

**Using `error_log`:**

To expand on others responses about `error_log` output, if it's an array or something that's not a string, it's best to use `print_r` and set return to `true`:

```
error_log( 'MY STUFF: ' . print_r( $something, true ) );
```